# Mapping site (again) - Moderators

Tags: discussion

So this [mapping site](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/558/ideas-for-a-worldbuilders-mapping-site) is coming along well now. Registrations are up (meaning feel free to go and register), the next job is logins and the rest of the pages.

However, I have now come across the problem of moderation. I don't know what kind of uptake this site is going to have, but I would like some help with running it. So, some ideas I've had:

- I could ask this community for volunteers to help moderate.
  This seems fair but it does open the door for someone to come in and start destroying things.
- I could give the three moderators here automatic mod accounts there.
  This means I can trust them, but they do have plenty of work to do here.

I don't know which of these would be best, so some thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: If your site has a history that can be restored, so that a rogue mod making large changes/deletions can always be reversed, then you can trust people until they demonstrate a reason not to. If your mods will have access to make irreversible changes then you'd have to choose them very carefully and make regular back ups.

Comment: It's in development at the moment. To be honest, implementing  a history system on my own would take a very long time so I'd rather have trustworthy mods. I could make backups though, making a manual history system.

Comment: The idea of having our mods here be involved is awesome if they're willing to do it. They've already proven that they're extremely responsible - and good at the job. By the way, would this site make a good community promotion ad?

Comment: @HDE226868 a community promotion ad sounds like a great idea.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Would you be up to making one?

Comment: @HDE226868 possibly, though I don't know what makes a good community promotion ad

Comment: Note to everyone: The site can be found [here](http://worldbuilders.hol.es/).

Comment: @HDE226868 Is there a set of guidelines for making community ads? Or some set of accepted ways of doing it?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Are you aware of http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @JanDoggen Aware, yes. Member, no. However, I value this community's input more as they will be the people using it

Comment: @ArtOfCode Just pointing out because expertise about generic issues like 'how to protect against a rogue moderator?' is over there ;-)

Comment: True, I'll have a look

Comment: If you need any help let me know.

Comment: This site has been offline for a years now. A meta question about it does now exist: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6001/remove-now-off-topic-questions-that-were-barely-on-topic-previously

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm glad to see that you're making progress on this great project!  I expect this to be very helpful to many of our users.

Speaking only for myself, I'd like to avoid blurring the line between SE moderation and moderation on your mapping site.  Even if some of the same people end up moderating both, I'd be more comfortable if you didn't just automatically make WB.SE mods also mapping-site mods.  You should be free to go in whatever direction you like without depending on SE's decisions about who our mods are.  And this would be a great opportunity for some people who *aren't* already mods here to get some moderation experience, if they're interested.

So my recommendation is that you either ask individuals directly or ask interested people to apply directly to you.  Either way, it'd be a good idea for you to have a description of what the moderation duties on your site are, so that people can decide if that matches their experience and interests.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to hold off accepting for now to see what other opinions I get, but I like the thinking.

Comment: This. And do seriously consider adding at least history functionality to your site. It *will* make things *much* easier, and it's much easier to have that from the beginning than trying to work it in afterwards. (Speaking from experience with something not entirely dissimilar.)

Comment: What I might do is set up automatic daily backups, then have an admin control page from which I can restore them... Kind of half-manual, half-automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a history that can be restored:

An easy fix is to create a field in your database that stores a value of Y or N, to show or hide comments, posts, uploads etc. This way when your moderators nix a particular item, a simple N would be inserted into your db, effectively hiding the item from public view. This would always allow you the ability to change that back to Y, to restore history.